# Authentification Failure errors after installing Ubuntu 10.04 on Samsung 305V5A

Tags: system-installation, 10.04, amdgpu

I bought a Samsung 305C5A-SO2 laptop running an AMD A8 Quad Core.

I have a CD for Ubuntu 10.04, but I am not clear about whether to install Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit. I thought I would try running an Ubuntu live session from the CD to see.

After about 30 minutes I started getting "Authentification Failure" messages.

> Squashfs-error  Unable to read fragment cache entry

Then I received over 17,000 "Buffer Logical" error messages!

Should I go download 11.10, in 32-bit or go and try the 64-bit?

I really don't want to foul up this new laptop already, but I'm not interested in working with Windows 7 either.

Comment: That is an error with the LiveCD/USB filesystem, it might be corrupted so re-Download the ISO and once you get it to install update the kernel because the CPU is brand new Llano CPUs are new and the newest kernel should be better for these CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Ubuntu 11.10 from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). 32bit or 64 bit, either will work fine on your laptop.
2. Follow the directions at the link to make a bootable CD or USB stick. Click the 'Show me how' button to see that you are doing the steps correctly.
3. Install Ubuntu following the guide on the same page as above.
4. If you still have errors after following the guide exactly, post the error messages up here with any specifics. Try to copy any error messages you see word-for-word. This helps us both.
5. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Tom Thanks for that. This was going to be my next step tomorrow I was also going to boot from the cd and install into a separate partition to bypass w7. I am still not sure, would you recommend 32bit or 64 in the end seems to be a lot of conflicting stuff. Thanks

Comment: If you have >4GB RAM, 64 bit can use it more efficiently. 32 bit is compatible with more applications, especially older ones. Don't spend much time worrying about it. If you ask ten people which they prefer you will get ten different answers. All would be correct. The suggested default now is 32 bit, so use that.

Comment: Regardless of the Memory amount 32 bit can take more than 4GB it's a myth now, and specially for linux it's a non existant limitation that lives in peoples mind. 64bit is compatible for %99 of the software these days and works fine with older software and hardware. Seeing his is an A8 quad-core processor perfectly capable of using 64 bit instructions there's no need for him to keep using Legacy old 32 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @UriHerrera I wouldn't say non-existant limitation, 32bit still has a maximum of 2GB addressable by any one process which can really suck if you want to run a big database or something. PAE does work around some of the issues but not all. Anyway I agree that 64bit is the present and the future so go with that.

Comment: One can increase the addresable  memory one process can take, right?.

Comment: @tombrossman Hmmm  cd I made just goes clickety click then stops after a while after screen appeared with little purple man symbol. Cd appears to have wubi.exe on it tried butting from w7 but same. Tried making a dvd too. Should I try running ubuntu with wubi through windows?

Comment: @ Antony no way, Wubi is completely different. Wubi installs Ubuntu WITHIN an existing Windows install. You said you wanted to install Ubuntu directly to the drive. The instructions for that are at the link in my answer. Burn another Live CD, following the instructions exactly. It sounds like your first CD is no good.

Comment: So I downloaded 11.10 32bit
Put cd in and after the purple screen with the litle man just clickety click for a couple of minutes then stop. Tried a dvd and same.
Tried running wubi to see.
Installed ok but in the menu if I choose ubuntu HD just goes round and round..
What am I doing wrong?
Should I try and download the 64 version and make a cd of that?
Thanks all

Comment: P.s Tom  No I am not in the market for Wubi but if it didnt go in through cd thought i'd give it a try ... I also ripped a Dvd first time but that didnt work either as boot.. Will try a cd again but its getting depressing...

Comment: @Antony this thread has too many comments now, and would be better off in the chat. I can't guarantee an answer, but it is now a better option to use chat vs. continued comments.Chat is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201

Comment: Sorry Tom I have no experinece with stackexchange though I am now registered. I cant see ho  I contact you there?

Comment: @TomBrossman Tom I have registered with stacexchange but cant see how to meet you so I am writing a comment. I have tried 10's of cd's and a dvd. I have now also downloaded 64bit. Problem is always same now. Boot from cd get copyright line then a purple screen with a rectangle and little man symbol. If I leave it machine just zig zags till it get tired. Ig I hit return button when have purple screen get language option and 4 choices for running ubuntu. If I chosse any (like install) it just resterats,goes back to copyright and starts all over again. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks Tony

Comment: @uriherrera I have now also downloaded 64bit. Problem is always same now. Boot from cd get copyright line then a purple screen with a rectangle and little man symbol. Then to black screen, If I leave it machine just zig zags till it get tired. Ig I hit return button when have purple screen get language option and 4 choices for running ubuntu. If I chosse any (like install) it just resterats,goes back to copyright and starts all over again. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks Tony

Comment: @UriHerrera.. hi by setting nomedeset on the installation I have managed to install. However I cant boot I seems due to the Radion card. If I run the installation again and allow it to update during installation do you think it will fetch best kernel or driver to resolve?  Thanks Antony

Answer (score 1):

[Squashfs](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/) is the filesystem which resides on your live CD. As the CD is probably somewhat old, there may some scratches or other damages on it. This leads in most cases to the Squashfs errors. So it is a safe choice for you to download the latest Ubuntu CD or DVD and use it like [Tom suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/88444/236).